# Issue with UK Tourist Visa application with vfs

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

I am currently applying for a UK Tourist Visa from San Francisco. I scheduled an appointment to the Premium Service Center in San Francisco. When i tried to register, i dont see any options for Tourist visa on the vfs website https://mycart.vfsglobal.co.uk/MyCart/Home/ApplicantHome#no-back

How should I proceed?

Thanks for your help! I am on a tight timeline, so any tips are welcome.

[image]

Here are the list of options

[image]

Comment: Can you please list the given options?

Comment: Find attached a screenshot of the options. The field i need to select is "Reason for visit"

Comment: What nationality are you? What you appear to want is a "Standard Visitor Visa" but you may not need one. https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: This is strange, it almost looks like the wrong form is loaded. Can you double check if they have some other options for visitor visa appointments?

Comment: I am from Colombia. I checked all the US premium service center, and they all showed those identical options. 

When I selected Australia for example, there was the option visitor.

None of the options in the screenshot would work for Tourist visa right?

It is weird because I have my appointment scheduled but can not register for the services